# How do I do content encoding properly in node.js?

Tags: javascript, encoding, node.js

Given the following code

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text'});
    response.write("Okay – so recently I’ve started presenting a session to various groups involving the well known IOC container “StructureMap”", 'utf8');
    response.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

I get the output

> Okay â€“ so recently Iâ€™ve started
>   presenting a session to various groups
>   involving the well known IOC container
>   â€œStructureMapâ€ â€“ and despite
>   being pretty clear about the contents
>   of said talk Iâ€™m getting quite a bit
>   of backlash for demonstrating anything
>   that even remotely resembles service
>   location.

This is clearly wrong - but is it wrong because I've got the wrong encoding (UTF8 should do it... right?... right?) or is it wrong because node is doing something weird?

I am using the latest version of node, cloned from github master yesterday.

Comment: Do you have the correct header in the meta tag of the page? Has the text been written and saved in a text editor with a different encoding?

Comment: See below - look at the content-type :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want it to be downloaded as a text file with the proper encoding, you should use the `text/plain; charset=utf-8`content type. Simply using `text` isn't enough. I just tested it and it works as expected. Change `plain` to `html` to make the browser use its default styles on the text.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to get the content to be styled by the browser.

Comment: Yeah - it's cool - I know this stuff :-) - I actually want plain text for this one, as I'm dumping raw files from one place to another